# how to put ad banner in j2me using lwuit?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to put a advertisement banner at the bottom of the screen of my j2me application.
How can i set a container fixed at a position so even if the page is scrolled that specific container will be still visible?
If not some other way to put up a ad banner above or below the command buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the add image in a Button, set the layout of the form to `BorderLayout` and set the form to scrollable false. Place the button in `BorderLayout.SOUTH` and your content in a Container (that you can set to scrollable Y true) in the center e.g.:

```
myForm.setScrollable(false);
Button ad = new Button(adAction);
myForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
myForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, ad);
Container actualContent = new Container();
myForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, actualContent);
actualContent.setScrollableY(true);
```